# Jmeter: Extract random value from array obtained through JSON Extractor

Tags: jmeter

So I am using JSON Extractor to extract an Array from an Http request (similar to Cost=[1,2,3,4,5,6])

I want to randomly extract and input one of the values from the array into another HTTP request

My hope is that I can either extract a random value from the Array through the JSON Extractor itself or use one of the Post Processors to do so, but I am unsure of how to do so

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the [JSON Extractor Post Processor.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
Set the Match No to 0 (default) to extract a random value from the possible values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JSON structure like:

```
{
    "cost": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6
    ]
}
```

And want to get a random value out of it, the easiest way is going for [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) configured like:

[image]

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMESPath Examples](https://jmespath.org/examples.html)
- [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)